# How to slow down Java Swing Application

Tags: java, swing

I am making a game demo where only computers play, but it is way too fast. I need it to show every move.

The program uses a while loop and it doesn't have anything supporting event listeners.
It just requires computer to make moves.

Comment: `Thread.sleep` could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a background task that triggers the moves and waits appropriately between moves. Something like:

```
Runnable moveTask = new Runnable () {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(...);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(theActualMoveHere());
        }
    }
}
new Thread(moveTask).start();
```

You would need to add a stopping mechanism (via interrupts) and probably sophisticate the logic but the basic idea should work.

Alternatively to sleeping, you could schedule the moves with a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) every x milliseconds for example. Note that the resolution of Timer is not very good, possibly as high as 30ms, so it might not be precise enough for you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use thread sleep method to wait X time. Some thing as:

```
Thread.sleep(4000);
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

If you need to loop a certain number of times per second, you could calculate the time each iteration have used and then sleep the needed time. For example:

```
boolean cont = true;
long time0, timeForEach = 1000, time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (cont) {

// Do my things here.

time0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
try {
  if (timeForEach > time0-time1) {
    Thread.sleep(timeForEach - (time0-time1));
  }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
time1 = time0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When I want to slow down things in code, I usually use timers, sleep or wait functions.
You probably have a function which is iterating/looping (for, while, for in, etc) for every move or something like that. You could put time between every iteration of such a loop.

Another tactic is to have the computer generate all of the moves it's going to make before they are shown to the end user. Then when you're showing every move to the user you can decide what the time spent on a single move is.